# Saving a DataFrame to .txt-file in R (every value in new line)

Tags: r, dataframe, save, tidyverse, txt

for quite some time I am trying to save a Dataframe to a txt-file with every entry of the Dadaframe in a new line. (But not all Column should be saved)

So for my example:

| A | B | column not to save |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Second | Value |
| Third | Fourth | Value |

My created .txt file then should look like this:

```
first
Second
Third
Fourth
```

I would show you my attempts of doing this, but so far I have no idea, how to do this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain I've 100% grasped what you're trying to do, but it looks like you're trying to print the data row-wise to a text file. Here's a possible solution using `tidyverse`. I'm not sure what your data looks like, so here's a slightly longer `tibble` just to show that it's doing what I'm seeing your question as.

To create some data for the example:

```
## if you need to install tidyverse
# install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

dat <-
  tibble(
    w = c("First", "Fourth", "Seventh"),
    x = c("Second", "Fifth", "Eighth"),
    y = c("Third", "Sixth", "Ninth"),
    z = c("do", "not", "want")
  )
```

The data looks like this:

```
w       x       y       z
First   Second  Third   do  
Fourth  Fifth   Sixth   not 
Seventh Eighth  Ninth   want
```

Here we're manipulating the data to the format you want printed.

```
dat_to_print <-
  dat %>%
  ## whatever columns you do not want printed would go here
  ## you could also select(w,x,y) instead of dropping the unwanted columns
  select(-z) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  ## whatever columns you want printed would go here... you can also provide it as c(w,x,y)
  pivot_longer(w:y) %>%
  ## pivot longer will come up with two columns: 
  ## the first is 'name' which holds the former name of the variable (i.e. w, x, or y)
  ## the second is 'value' which is what you want to print as I've understood the problem
  ## it doesn't look like you care about the old column names, so we remove it here
  select(-name)
```

And creating the text file.

```
write.table(dat_to_print, 
            file = "C:\\your\\folder\\location\\dat.txt", 
            col.names = FALSE, 
            row.names = FALSE, 
            quote = FALSE)
```

`dat.txt` will look like this:

```
First               
Second              
Third               
Fourth              
Fifth               
Sixth               
Seventh             
Eighth              
Ninth
```